# How to return a struct whose property has a type of &str from a function in rust?

Tags: rust, struct, borrow-checker

I am trying to do the following

```rust
// Just removes redundant white space while also splitting the string
// with a whitespace.
fn split_whitespace(string: &str) -> Vec<&str> {
    let words: Vec<&str> = string
        .split_whitespace()
        .filter(|&word| word != "")
        .collect();
    words
}

pub fn get_websites_from_hosts(hosts_path: &Path) -> Result<Vec<Website>, std::io::Error> {
    let hosts_string = read_to_string(hosts_path)?;

    let result: Vec<Website> = hosts_string
        .lines()
        .filter(|&line| split_whitespace(&line.to_owned()).len() == 2)
        .map(|line| {
            let ip_domain = split_whitespace(&line.to_owned());
            Website {
                domain_name: ip_domain[1], // This won't work because it is refering hosts_string which is a local variable of the function
                redirect_ip: ip_domain[0], // the same case with this one.
                is_blocked: true,
                hosts_path,
            }
        })
        .collect();

    Ok(result)
}
```

What I want to achieve is to successfully return the Website struct while probably not editing the struct declaration.

And here is the Website struct declaration

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Website<'a> {
    pub domain_name: &'a str,
    pub redirect_ip: &'a str,
    pub is_blocked: bool,
    pub hosts_path: &'a Path,
}
```

And here is the error

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/parser.rs:21:13
   |
20 |               let ip_domain = split_whitespace(&line.to_owned());
   |                                                 --------------- temporary value created here
21 | /             Website {
22 | |                 domain_name: ip_domain[1],
23 | |                 redirect_ip: ip_domain[0],
24 | |                 is_blocked: true,
25 | |                 hosts_path,
26 | |             }
   | |_____________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
error: could not compile `website-blocker` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: could not compile `website-blocker` due to previous error
```

I would love a deep explanation and general tips to use when encountering this and the like problems

Comment: You can't return a struct that references a local var that goes out of scope.

Comment: Unless you can prove to the compiler (with lifetime annotations) that the referenced data outlives the struct. Which is not possible in this case, because it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&str` references in your struct refer to segments of the string returned by `read_to_string`. That string (`hosts_string`) is dropped and deallocated at the end of `fn get_websites_from_hosts`, so if you could return references to it, they would be dangling. Rust prevents you from doing that.

Instead, you'll need to either move the `read_to_string` outside that function, and pass the string in as an `&str` or change your struct to hold owned values like `String`, [`IpAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/net/enum.IpAddr.html), etc.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Website<'a> {
    pub domain_name: String,
    pub redirect_ip: IpAddr,
    pub is_blocked: bool,
    pub hosts_path: &'a Path,
}
```

If you want to avoid some `String` allocations, you could use a "small-string optimization" library like [`compact_str`](https://docs.rs/compact_str/latest/compact_str/)

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Website<'a> {
    // Stores a domain name of up to 24 bytes in place,
    // without an extra heap allocation
    pub domain_name: CompactString,
    pub redirect_ip: IpAddr,
    pub is_blocked: bool,
    pub hosts_path: &'a Path,
}
```

Comment: What do you think is better to use as struct property types to start with, owned or referenced( its cuz i am a beginner :) )

Comment: Owned are certainly easier as a beginner, and I often use them when prototyping.